# Remove a specific letter from form input

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Within `clean()`, I am attempting to check if the User included "#" in the `SearchHashtagForm` and, if so, remove it.

For example, assume that User enters "#foo" on the `SearchHashtagForm`:

**EXPECTED 'search_text'**: "foo"

**ACTUAL 'search_text'**: "#foo"

I suspect that the line: `form_input = form_input[1:]` doesn't work, but I'm not sure what else to use?

**Views.py**

```
class HashtagSearch(FormView):
    """ FormView for user to enter hashtag search query """

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.clean()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class SearchHashtagForm(ModelForm):
    """ ModelForm for user to search by hashtag """

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        form_input = cleaned_data.get('search_text')
        if form_input.startswith('#'): # if input starts with '#', remove it.
            form_input = form_input[1:]
            cleaned_data['search_text'] = form_input
        return cleaned_data
```

## SOLVED

In the interests of being succinct, I omitted the line: `self.get_tweets(form)` from `form_valid()` from the original query. I have provided by a more complete copy of the code, along with the solution, below:

As the solution, I removed `clean()` and instead included `lstrip("#")` (as suggested by below) in both `get_success_url` and `get_tweets()`.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return '{}?search_text={}'.format(
        reverse('mapping_twitter:results'),
        self.request.POST.get('search_text').lower().lstrip("#"),
    )

def form_valid(self, form):
    self.get_tweets(form)
    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_tweets(self, form):
    ...
    search_filter = self.request.POST.get('search_text').lower().lstrip("#")
    ...
    tweet_object, created = Hashtag.objects.get_or_create(search_text=search_filter)
    ...
```

Comment: what datatype does cleaned_data['search_text'] have?

Comment: @KGM `CharField`

Comment: if it does not work, form_input is no string, but something else.

Comment: if it is CharField, try CharField.value_to_string and print the result

Comment: This `form_input = form_input[1:]` should be `form_input[] = form_input[1:]`.  By doing this you are storing the value in a separate list

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha that's completely incorrect.

Comment: what is in form_input seems to be a string (form_input.startswith('#') would work with string, but form_input = form_input[1:] should work, too(!?))?

Comment: @DanielRoseman OPs code looks fine to me. I thought their might be a referencing issue in slicing. Whats wrong with making a copy of `form_input`

Comment: Nothing, but `form_input[] = ...` is invalid syntax in Python.

Comment: awww! MAYBE THERE ARE SOME OTHER TRAILING CHARACTERS YOU DON'T SEE! AND BY DOING s[1:], YOU SLICE AWAY SOMETHING INVISIBLE!

Comment: @ycrad I can't see anything wrong with the code you've posted, but you might try putting that logic in `clean_search_text` rather than the general clean method (and just return form_input). Also note you don't need to call `form.clean()` manually in the view; you should remove the whole `form_valid` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for the thorough feedback. I have amended the query above with the solution.

Comment: Actually, looking at your updated code, the problem is that you are using `self.request.POST.get('search_text')` in `get_tweets` instead of `form.cleaned_data['search_text']`.

Comment: Yes, I know realize that the issue was that: `search_filter = self.request.POST.get('search_text')` was undoing any work done in `clean()`. As the above solution works, is it desirable to instead of remove "#" in `clean()`, or it is sufficient to do so as done above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip), to remove the unwanted characters from the starting of your string as:

```
>>> tag = "#foo"
>>> tag.lstrip("#")
>>> "foo"

>>> tag = "foo"
>>> tag.lstrip("#")
>>> "foo"

>>> tag = "#foo#bar"
>>> tag.lstrip("#")
>>> "foo#bar"
```

This will also save you the extra method calls to check if the string starts with `"#"` or not, it implicitly handles it and does nothing if the `tag` does not start with the desired `"#"`.

Answer (score 1):

if form_input = form_input[1:] and form_input.startswith('#') don't throw errors,

Maybe you've got a normal string (else Idk why slicing and .startswith('#') should work) that starts with n invisible trailing characters before the # you see.

if thats the case, just try :

```
form_input = form_input[2:]

form_input = form_input[3:]

form_input = form_input[4:]

...
```

and see if you get reasonable results.

(print form_input and see what comes out)

if this does not work, you most likely have some werid datatype in form input.

obtain type and value of form input and add those to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too:

```
''.join(filter(lambda x: x != '#', '#foo'))
# foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this

```
import re

class SearchHashtagForm(ModelForm):
""" ModelForm for user to search by hashtag """

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    form_input = cleaned_data.get('search_text')
    re.sub('[#]','', form_input)     
    cleaned_data['search_text'] = form_input
    return cleaned_data
```

This will replace all the characters in the string matching '#'. This solution is more robust since you can check for more characters like "%". for instance

```
re.sub('[#%]','', form_input)
```